# displaying datePicker through angularController

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on angularjs application.I' having trouble to load the script to show the calendar in the Choose Date field in my local workspace.

I tried below two ways.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    alert("in addEventListener");
    //js code to display daterangepicker.
 });
```

When page is loading, the alert "in addEventListener" is getting displayed but the daterangepicker is not displayed in the Choose Date text field.

Another approach is as below, when page loads alert statement "document.ready function" is getting displayed but daterangepicker is not showing in the input field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 alert("document.ready function");

 //js code to display daterangepicker.
});
```

js code to display daterangepicker.

```
var cb = function(start, end, label) {
            console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
            console.log("Callback has fired: [" + start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ", label = " + label + "]");
        }

        var optionSet1 = {
            startDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
            endDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
            minDate: '08/01/2014',
            maxDate: '12/31/2017',
            dateLimit: {
                days: 60
            },
            showDropdowns: true,
            showWeekNumbers: true,
            timePicker: false,
            timePickerIncrement: 1,
            timePicker12Hour: true,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            },
            opens: 'left',
            buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
            applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
            cancelClass: 'btn-small',
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            separator: ' to ',
            locale: {
                applyLabel: 'Submit',
                cancelLabel: 'Clear',
                fromLabel: 'From',
                toLabel: 'To',
                customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
                daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
                monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                firstDay: 1
            }
        };

        $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY'));

        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);

        $('#reportrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
          alert("show event fired");
            console.log("show event fired");
        });
        $('#reportrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function() {
          alert("hide event fired");
            console.log("hide event fired");
        });
        $('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        });
        $('#reportrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            console.log("cancel event fired");
        });
```

html :

```
 <input id="reportrange">
```

The code is working fine in plunker demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dUVDf5MHooJmGmmD1D27?p=preview) but not in my local workspace. I tried hard to figure the problem but no luck.

**Can i write the js code which is used to display daterangepicker inside the angular controller method** , in that way i can hit the backend code and get the ranges for minDate and maxDate. Please advice.
Please find the demo code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TCI4W7gpdCcMEGbcJnEX?p=preview)

Comment: Why are you using all this jQuery in an AngularJS application? I see nothing here that is specific to AngularJS.

Comment: @BenBeck - Please see the link http://plnkr.co/edit/TCI4W7gpdCcMEGbcJnEX?p=preview . dateRangePicker to be displayed in my angularjs application.

Comment: though surely doing what you are doing isnt good. if you can elaborate a little more on the errors you might be getting  in the console. or anything you in the page source it would be nice

Comment: @participantjava, why wouldn't you use [Bootstrap UI Datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#datepicker) so you're not mixing jQuery into your AngularJS application?

Comment: Parv Sharma - I'm not getting any errors. Issue is as said in my post, i have to load the dateRangePicker when the page is loaded and i need to pass min and maxDates dynamically getting from backend to the dateRangePicker function so that it will enable dates between that range. However i'm facing issues when trying to integrate daterangepicker code with angularjs. I'm sure its confusing but the issue is i want to show dateRangePicker retrieving minDate and maxDate dynamically from backend..so tried t show the code in plnkr.co/edit/TCI4W7gpdCcMEGbcJnEX?p=preview

Comment: @BenBeck - I want the DateRangePicker so that users can select multiple dates and the functionality should be same as shown in http://plnkr.co/edit/dUVDf5MHooJmGmmD1D27?p=preview, it has multiple options to show last week,last month data too..